# Class yii\debug\Module does not exist

Tags: exception, reflection, yii2

I am trying to run my Yii2 application on Vagran virtual machine. As provison I use Ansible. Here is my ansible playbook file:

```
---
- hosts: vagrant
  sudo: true
  tasks:
- name: 1. install Apache
  apt: name=apache2 state=present

- name: 1.1 Delete temporary file
  file: path=/var/www/web/index.html state=absent

- name: 2. install PHP module for Apache
  apt: name=php5 state=latest update_cache=yes

- name: 3. Install PHP GD library
  apt: name=php5-cli state=latest

- name: 4. Start Apache
  service: name=apache2 state=running enabled=yes

- name: 5. Install MySQL
  apt: pkg=mysql-server state=present

- name: 6. Install python-mysqldb
  apt: pkg=python-mysqldb state=present

- name: 7. Install PHP MySQL bindings
  apt: pkg=php5-mysql state=present

- name: 8. Restart apache
  service: name=apache2 state=restarted

- name: 9. Set MySQL root password
  debconf: name='mysql-server' question='mysql-server/root_password' value='password' vtype='password'

- name: 10. Confirm MySQL root password before installing
  debconf: name='mysql-server' question='mysql-server/root_password_again' value='password' vtype='password'

- name: 11. Database creation with name gitSearch 
  mysql_db: name=gitSearch state=present

- name: 12.a Copy database dump
  copy: src=../gitSearch.sql.bz2 dest=/tmp/gitSearch.sql.bz2 

- name: 12.b Copy database dump
  mysql_db: name=gitSearch state=import target=/tmp/gitSearch.sql.bz2

- name: 13. Ensure curl is installed
  apt: pkg=curl state=installed
  when: ansible_os_family == 'Debian'

- name: 14. Install Composer into the current directory
  shell: >
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
    creates=/usr/local/bin/composer

- name: 15. Install php5-curl
  apt: name=php5-curl state=latest update_cache=yes

- name: 16. Move Composer into globally-accessible location.
  shell: >
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
    creates=/usr/local/bin/composer

- name: 18. Update dependencies v2
  composer: command=install working_dir=/var/www
```

When I run my project I have an exception:

```
ReflectionException

Class yii\debug\Module does not exist
in /var/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php
```

I think the problem is with composer, because before provision gets to composer tasks everything is fine. On my local machine (not Vagrant box) everything was fine too. Debugger section in config:

```
$config['modules']['debug']['class'] = 'yii\debug\Module';
$config['modules']['debug']['allowedIPs'] = ['*'];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the Debug module and/or the Gii modules aren't installed.

Please check the `composer.json` file in the root of your yii2 project, and make sure that the following lines are present in the `require-dev` section of the composer file: `"yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0"` and `"yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0"`.

Then run `composer update` in the root of your project.

If that is not the problem, you're probably [running the application with the wrong permissions.](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver)

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks! The problem occurred because of invalid composer execution via Ansible. Now it works!)

Comment: Great! Also, you made me learn about Ansible; it's really an amazing tool.